# Syntax for tRest component to upload local file Talend

Tags: rest, http, talend

So i have to upload text file to server with PUT request, i know there is similar solution but as it seems, not only for me it is generating errors:
[solution generating error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38164930/how-to-upload-files-using-talend-trest)

I know there is possibility to this this with tFileFetch component but it only support POST request.

My current job looks like this:

[talend Job](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPRuT.png)

And my question is how to write correct syntax in HTTP body to upload local file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't get `tREST` to upload a file with the PUT http method. I'm pretty sure it's not possible. You should be able to do it with a custom java code though, that you can find in this [article](http://talend.nl/talend-tech-tip-calling-a-rest-service-for-file-upload/).

Comment: Is it possible for tRest to use POST http method to upload file? well i think i ll end up with custom java component  but just to be sure.

Comment: I don't believe so, since the http body is just string.. If you can afford to use POST, the `tFileFetch` does that (as in the link you posted)